# how to compare the previous loss and current loss in custom loss function

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, loss-function

I want to ask how to build a custom loss function that has the data of previous loss results. I am trying to build CNN to predict how many images are left before events happen. Therefore the y_pred is monotonously decreasing, and I want to put a penalty term if the model does not predict monotonically.

Thank you in advance!

for example

```
def violation loss():
   previous_loss_value = ##_what I want to ask_##

def my_loss(y_true,y_pred):

    violation = max(previous_loss_value - y_pred, 0) 
    
    loss =  MSE + violation                 
    return loss
return my_loss
```